# python - add mock for requests.get without need to explicitly check it

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking

I want to add `requests` mock for python.
Any call to `requests.get` in a class will call the unittest mock function instead.

I don't want to add a call such as `requests.get` in the unittest itself, it may happen in many places in code.

Now, changes on code - I get:

> `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='myurl1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /test.txt (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fbc5da52e00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve'))`

i.e:

in main class: `my_class`

```
import requests
from urllib import request, parse
...

mymock = None

class MyClass():

   def myfunc1(self):
       ...
       # requests.get can be callled randomaly
       requests.get('http://myurl1/test.txt')
       
   
   def myfunc2(self):
       requests.get('http://myurl2/test.txt')
```

and the unittest:

```
from s3_uploader import *
import pytest
import mock
import requests
import requests_mock

class MyMockClass(MyClass):
    @requests_mock.mock()
    def mock_get_requests(self, m):
        m.get('http://myurl1/test.txt')
        # if I call here to the base class myfunc1.myfunc1 - there is no exception
        # but I don't want to implement like this (call the main function whenever the mock is declared):

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        mymock.mock_get_requests()
        
    def test_myfunc1(self)
        super.myfunc1() # this raise exception - the mock for request.get is not injected to the request.get class
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mymock = MyMockClass()
    unittest.main()
```

I don't want to do something like the following (which works, but I need to do it for lot of functions, and http `requests.get` is not the only mock).

```
class MyMockClass(MyClass):
    def mock_get_requests(self, m):
        m.get('http://myurl1/test.txt')
        super.myfunc1()
        

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @requests_mock.mock(self)
    def test_myfunc1(self, m)
        mymock.mock_get_requests()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mymock = MyMockClass()
    unittest.main()
```

Also I tried using the [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html)

This also use the original `requests.get` and not the mocked one.

Like this:

```
class MockResponse:
    @staticmethod
    def json():
        return {"mock_key": "mock_response"}


# monkeypatched requests.get moved to a fixture
@pytest.fixture
def mock_response(monkeypatch):
    """Requests.get() mocked to return {'mock_key':'mock_response'}."""

    def mock_get(*args, **kwargs):
        return MockResponse()

    logging.info('**** test mock response ****')
    monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "get", mock_get)
```

and in test class:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mock_response")
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
...
    def test_requests(self):
        requests.get(http://myurl/test.txt') # this not using the mock
        # mymock.myfunc1 doesn't work either.
```

What may be the alternative solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Question is bit confusing, you can use `monkeypatch.setattr` [pytest monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html) , Do you want your mock to invoke different responses depending on the urls ?

Comment: I tried - didn't succeed.
In MyClass, which is the class that I test (it not a unittest class), there is a call to requests.get, but requests.get calls actually the original requests.get function an d not the mocked one.

Comment: It seems that unittest.TestCase not working well, while just function start wit: test_ works.
and python -m pytest my_test.py works with @pytest wrapping. I will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following test code where **I didn't use `pytest`**:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from my_class import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch("my_class.requests")
    def test_func1(self, mock_requests):
        sut = MyClass()
        sut.myfunc1()
        mock_requests.get.assert_called_once_with('http://myurl1/test.txt')

    @mock.patch("my_class.requests")
    def test_func2(self, mock_requests):
        sut = MyClass()
        sut.myfunc2()
        mock_requests.get.assert_called_once_with('http://myurl2/test.txt')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I suppose that:

1. for you is enough to test that `myfunc1` and `myfunc2` call `request.get()` with a precise URL;
2. the class `MyClass` is contained in the file `my_class.py` (see the import `from my_class import MyClass`).

When tests call functions `myfunc1` and `myfunc2`, they don't call the real `requests.get()` function but the 2 tests contain necessarily the instruction: `@mock.patch("my_class.requests")`, so I don't know if this solution is suited to answer to your question.